# Max returning multiple values

Tags: sql

I'm being required to group with the Max statement but I'm getting multiple lines per user_id.  I only want the most recent tracked_date_id for each user_id.

```
SELECT max(tracked_date_id) as weigh_in_date, dm.user_id, dp.description, fm.next_bill_date_id, wt.weight_in_lbs, dm.goal_weight
 FROM `datalake.star_schema.fact_billing` fm
 inner join `datalake.star_schema.dim_member` dm
 on dm.member_id = fm.member_id
 inner join `datalake.star_schema.dim_product` dp
 on dp.product_id = fm.product_id
 inner join `datalake.star_schema.fact_weight_tracking` wt 
 on wt.member_id = dm.member_id 
 where
  dm.life_time_flag = "True" and
 dm.is_fran_flag = "False" and
 dm.classic_country = "US" and
 dp.description like '%Lifetime%' and
cast(fm.next_bill_date_id as string) like '%20221001%' 
group by 2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: If you want one result per userid, why are you grouping by 4 other columns as well? What do you believe thst accomplishes for you?  (Please also fully qualify the columns, it's currently impossible to tell which table the tracked date comes from.)

Comment: The max is per whatever the level of grouping you prescribe with your additional fields (i.e, max date per *user-description-nextbilling-weight-goal* which is probably a lot more groups than just max date per *user*

Comment: Oh, and which RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Big Query? They all have different functionality and syntax.